# Difference between returning and not returning in recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I have written a program to print the Kth node from root of a binary tree.

```
// PRINT KTH NODE FROM ROOT (FUNCTION 1)
void printKth(node *root, int k){
    if (root == NULL){
        return;
    }
    if (k == 0){
        cout<<root -> data<<" ";
        return;
    }

    printKth(root -> left, k-1);
    printKth(root -> right, k-1);
}
```

For the below binary tree, The code prints

```
//          100     
//         /   \
//       80     120
//      /  \
//    40    60
// 
// OUTPUT - 80 120
```

The above function works fine until I add a return statement in the second and third last lines.

```
// PRINT KTH NODE FROM ROOT (FUNCTION 2)
void printKth(node *root, int k){
    if (root == NULL){
        return;
    }
    if (k == 0){
        cout<<root -> data<<" ";
        return;
    }

    return printKth(root -> left, k-1);    // ADDED RETURN STATEMENT
    return printKth(root -> right, k-1);   // ADDED RETURN STATEMENT
}
```

For the below binary tree, The code prints

```
//          100     
//         /   \
//       80     120
//      /  \
//    40    60
// 
// OUTPUT - 80
```

I can't understand what's happening when adding the return statement.

Comment: `return` returns immediately. Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions.

Comment: Code after `return` statement is unreachable (compiler might warn about that).

Comment: think about how would you terminate a recursive function?

Comment: Suppose you were calling two entirely different functions, `f` and `g`. Would you expect `return f(); return g();` to call `g` at any point?

Comment: @Jarod42, my mistake; never seen that before.

Comment: The effect of your changes (adding the `return` keyword) is that the second version of your function returns immediately after the call of `printKth(root -> left, k-1)`.   The call of `printKth(root -> right, k-1)` in the first version of your function never happens in the second version - because there is a `return` statement immediately (and unconditionally) preceding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special about recursive functions. The second you `return` you are no longer evaluating the rest. You see that in your base cases since they don't evaluate the rest. When you add return the result of the call is returned and the last statement is never reached.

You function doesn't print the kth node but every node in the kth level in your first version. If you were to print the kth node you would have to return the current k and if it is still positive continue to recurse into the right tree.